# Minecraft "Connection Lost Timed Out"

Tags: minecraft

Hello I have been running Minecraft fine on Ubuntu 15.10, but I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Now I can play Minecraft single player, but when I want to connect to a server it initially connects, but after around 20 seconds, it gives me "Connection Lost Timed Out". What should I do to fix this?

Comment: and sorry my english is bad

Comment: Help please ? i really want to play minecraft.

Comment: If you are playing via WiFi connection problems can be related to the WiFi driver. Have you tried using ethernet cable connection?

Comment: @TheFisch I'm using WiFi and no i didn't.I'm going to try now if it gives any error again i'll write again.Thanks for Reply

Comment: @TheFisch I don't know how to thank you.It works but how can i fix wifi driver?

Comment: Your welcome. Unstable Wifi on 14.04. seems to be a common problem and there are a lot threads dealing with that stuff. The solution might differ depending on your network adapter.

Comment: eg see the solution here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219014&p=12998326#post12998326 or search for "ubuntu 14.04. unstable wifi"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with minecraft in recent weeks. It wouldn't always start, so I had to kill it a few times before it would work, and it would get slow at connecting to servers.

My solution was [installing the Oracle Java 8 runtime](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html).

Comment: I just upgraded my Ubuntu and downloaded Java 8 it worked fine.Thanks for replying and help :>

Comment: It is not a good practice to share only link since the link can be changed or removed anytime. Yet, you can share the link as reference to your answer